# Lightning App builder Filter List Error

Tags: lightning-apps, lightning

While using the Lightning App Builder on my dev org, I put a standard `Filter List` component onto the canvas. Once it is there, in the properties pane I am seeing this error on every filter I try and select both OOTB and custom.

[image: Lightning App Builder Filter List Error]

I tried the same process on a sandbox spun off of a production org and it is not happening. Both the sandbox and my personal dev org have custom domains enabled.

Does anyone have any thoughts or ideas as to why, or something I may be missing?